# how to redirect user number to phone call app flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way I can redirect a user to his/her phone call app with a number when he/she clicks a button?

**for a better explanation:**

I have an app where you can check people's profiles and then when you click a button in someone's profile. it will redirect you to your phone call app with the person's number from his profile and then choose to call him/her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `url_launcher: ^5.7.10` in you Pubspec.yaml

run `flutter pub get`

and you can use this function,

```
call() async {
  const tel= {phone number};
  try {
        await launch(tel);
  } catch (_e) { print(_e):} 

}
```

watch out for indentation
regards,
Roshan

Answer (score 1):

Above the version `url_launcher: 6.1.0` The launch function is deprecated, use the function launchUrl instead

```
final Uri smsLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'tel',
  path: 'my phone number'
);
await launchUrl(smsLaunchUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the url launcher package.

It has the ability to open the correct app depending on what you pass to it in the coded url. For example, if you pass it has http url, it opens the browser. If you pass smtp coded phone number, it opens sms app etc

Url parameter of tel: will launch your phone app

Details [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: consider adding some explanation

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan fair. For the question, I felt just the mention of package was sufficient. But yes, for other readers an explanation helps